# Мертвы ли списки? C

Tags: c, память, структуры-данных, data-structures

Изучаю структуры данных и алгоритмы, работал с чужими исходниками и не раз видел реализацию "бесконечного буфера" с помощью `realloc`, всегда реализовывал свой вариант поблочным выделением, и оставлением указателя на следующий блок.

```
struct Node{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
}
```

Появились следующие вопросы:

- Как затратней, realloc или моя реализация?
- [Почему создатель связного списка его не использует?](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/583813919019573248)
- Как работает класс `vector` в C++?
- Почему в `C++` есть аналог `malloc`, `calloc` и `free` (`new`, `new []`, `delete`), но нет аналога `realloc`?

Пожалуйста приведите как реализовываете вы, как лучше, почему.

**UPD**

- Что затратней выделять память или копировать один участок в другой (уже выделенный), на сколько затратней?

Comment: Оу, оказывается, это Блох - **создатель** связанного списка... Тогда я - создатель ответа на ruSO :)

Comment: `"Мертвы ли списки?"`. Если вас интересует, используют ли люди связные списки, то ответ, *конечно, да*. В тех случаях, когда это целесообразно по смыслу задачи. Стоит ли моделировать логически непрерывный буфер сегментами, организованными в список? Вопрос интересный, возможно, иногда это даст выигрыш (или (в случае нехватки памяти) просто позволит выполнить задачу), но "в среднем", навскидку, такое решение не выглядит целесообразным

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Архитектура современных компьютеров такова, что массивы (и любые структуры данных, основанные на них) оказываются в *большинстве* случаев быстрее, чем связные списки.

**Кеш**

Все дело в кеше. В одной линии кеша располагается сразу несколько элементов массива. Следовательно, при доступе к ним процессор не тратит много времени. А элементы связного списка с высокой долей вероятности не попадут в одну линию кеша. Следовательно, при обращении к очередному элементу будет промах и процессору придётся обращаться к основной памяти.

**Память**

Английское название - RAM (random access memory) - *память со случайным доступом* - давным-давно стало неправильным обозначением этого типа памяти. На самом деле она давно является блочной. Кстати, русское ОЗУ (оперативное запоминающее устройство), не несёт в своём определении такого недостатка.

Современная память устроена так, что пишет/читает данные большими порциями. Подготовка к чтению и записи (латентность) занимает много времени. Зато потом данные выстреливаются очень быстро. Нетрудно понять, что последовательно размещённый массив будет читаться и писаться намного быстрее, чем связный список, элементы которого размещены в разных банках памяти.

Answer (score 5):

- Как затратней, realloc или моя реализация?

Для *чего*? С точки зрения памяти, локальности, поиска, сортировки...? Как будете выделять память - каждый раз по одному элементу или сразу раза в 2 больший буфер и поддерживать его емкость/заполненность? Вопрос поставлен некорректно...

- Почему создатель связного списка его не использует?

А "создатель" - это кто? без этого непонятно, использует ли он его или нет...

**Update** С тем же успехом, что считать Блоха создателем связанного списка, можно считать собравшего из разного железа в гараже велосипед слесаря дядю Васю - *создателем* велосипеда. Но дяде Васе просто некуда и незачем на нем ездить. Как и у Блоха, вероятно, нет задач, для которых связанный список более подходящ, чем массив...

- Как работает класс `vector` в C++?

Поддерживая буфер, увеличиваемый по заполнении в некоторое количество раз - например, в два, так что обычно в нем есть достаточно пустого места для новых элементов. Когда заполняется - выделяется новый буфер удвоенного размера, куда перекопируется содержимое старого. Так что в результате амортизированное количество копирований - O(1), а все данные хранятся в одном блоке памяти.

- Почему в C++ есть аналог `malloc`, `calloc` и `free` (`new`, `new[]`, `delete`), но нет аналога `realloc`?

Ну, я бы не говорил, что это аналоги, уж тем более что `new[]` - аналог `calloc`. Эти "аналоги" вызывают конструкторы и деструкторы, а при `realloc` это, скажем так, задача, которую непросто решить для нетривиальных типов. Это совсем не так просто, как в С -  перебросить память с одного места в другое...

Answer (score 4):

> Как затратней, realloc или моя реализация?

Выделение памяти- это дорогостоящий процесс.
Именно по этому память любят выделять с запасом.

Более того, происходит копирования всего старого блока памяти на новый участок памяти нового размера(если размер увеличивается).

Поэтому реализация без постоянного дерганья realloc более производительна.

> Как работает класс vector в C++?
>
> Типичная реализация вектора — это указатель на динамический массив.
>   Размер вектора — это фактическое число элементов, а объём — количество
>   используемой им памяти.
>
> Если при вставке в вектор новых элементов, его размер становится
>   больше его объёма, происходит перераспределение памяти. Как правило,
>   это приводит к тому, что вектор выделяет новую область хранения,
>   перемещая элементы и свободные старые области в новый участок памяти.

[Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(C%2B%2B))

Comment: Так ведь и при создании списка в большинстве случаев на каждый узел будет дергаться `malloc`...

Comment: Так-то realloc может неявно скопировать старые данные на новый участок памяти, что может быть медлительнее.