Эффективное решение задач, где нужно вставлять в элемент в середину массива
Есть задача о очереди. Нужно произвести n операций с ней. при вводе в консоль "P x" - человек с номером х встаёт в конец очереди. При вводе "M x" - человек с номером х встаёт в середину очереди, если в очереди нечётное количество человек, то он встаёт за центральным человеком. При вводе "C" - первый человек в очереди уходит. Гарантируется, что на момент такого запроса очередь не пуста. Нужно для каждой операции "C" вывести номер ушедшего человека. Если решать эту задачу просто вставляя и удаляя людей из очереди, то это требует много памяти и выполняется долго. Как можно решить эту задачу эффективно? Какие приёмы можно использовать для решения? Какие есть источники, чтобы научится решать такие задачи?

А вы с прошлой задачей ещё не закончили. Если разобрались, то не забудьте, если нет - то спрашивайте.

Как можно решить эту задачу эффективно? я вижу односвязный список со счетчиком элементов N и с запоминанием двух указателей - на head и tail. Тогда операция "P x" - это добавление элемента в конец (после tail), "M x" - это проход от head элемента вперед N/2 раза в случае нечетности N или N/2 -1 в случае четности, затем вставка элемента за текущим. "C" - это присваивание head адреса на следующий за head элемента.

@AndreiKhotko Вставка то будет быстрой, но вот проходить каждый раз половину списка в поисках середины - не айс. Можно, конечно, сделать двусвязный список и хранить ссылку на текущую середину, от которой потом уже идти в следующий раз до актуальной середины, когда это понадобится. Ну, тоже вариант.

Кэш побеждает асимптотику. Берём динамический массив (в C++ это vector<T>, в C# это List<T>) и он, несмотря на копирования элементов, окажется быстрее чем списки. Если только речь не о миллионах элементов.

Очередь - это абстрактное понятие, абстрактный тип данных. А реализация может быть самой разной. Что именно используете вы?

@AlexanderPetrov Кстати, да. Для небольшого кол-ва элементов блочное копирование довольно быстро делается на уровне инструкций процессора. Вопрос в том, какой тут размер очередей...

Уточню. Не обязательно брать именно vector в C++. Главное - коллекция, которая хранит элементы последовательно в памяти. Тогда они в линию кэша будут попадать вместе и быстро обрабатываться.

В общем, уточните: язык программирования, размер очереди, можно ли брать готовые коллекции или всё нужно реализовывать самому.

@AlexanderPetrov А можете пояснить, при чём здесь вообще кэш? Он улучшает скорость копирования областей памяти, фактически оно в кэше происходит, или каким боком тут кэш? Или вы про доставание элементов из очереди? Но оно и так O(1) почти при любом подходе и не будет слабым местом.

Или две очереди или односвяный список в котором поддерживаются указатели на начало, середину и конец. И то и другое делается не слишком сложно.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Две очереди - придется постоянно между ними метаться и перекидывать элементы (хотя это и простая операция); лучше уж одну с указателем на средину... А вообще, похоже, это какая-то олимпиадная задачка, о которой в очередной раз забыли рассказать точное условие с ограничениями...

@Harry Всё упирается в реальный размер очереди. И размер элементов этой очереди. Ну это ладно, можно хранить в очереди указатели на элементы. Если элементов мало, то низкоуровневое копирование что одного элемента, что тысячи, будет примерно одинаково "стоить". А вот для очереди в миллионы элементов вставка элемента в середину очереди будет гораздо накладнее, чем перекладывание нескольких элементов из одной очереди в другую. Впрочем, это нужно замерять на реальных данных. Кстати, это перекладывание ведь тоже можно сделать копированием. Копирование нескольких элементов будет быстрым.

@Harry, перекладывание только из второй очереди в первую. И оно происходит в два раза реже чем операции над концами очередей.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/951140/184217 - тут я писал про кэш и блочную память

@AlexanderPetrov Ну это больше про чтение... Хотя это хорошее напоминание о том, почему связные списки настолько непопулярны в реальной жизни и обычно всплывают только в учебных заданиях.

@CrazyElf, связные списки регулярно появляются в комбинаторном поиске. Но это конечно мало относится к реальной жизни. :)

Пчеловод, примите ответы в задаваемых вопросах. Люди голову ломают над вашими задачами, а вам только один клик сделать.

Ну, от хранения номеров в памяти вы не избавитесь. Вот насчёт времени можно что-то придумать. Погуглив подобные вопросы, я нашёл на английском СО вариант с разбиением очереди на 2 части. Плюс развил идею из вашего комментария.
Вариант 1
Просто делаете 2 очереди: для первой половины людей и для второй половины людей.
[очередь первой половины] [очередь второй половины]
 ^                       ^                       ^
 | начало                | середина              | конец

Тогда вставка в середину очереди будет сдвигать каждый раз не половину элементов очереди, а всего несколько. Которые лучше и не сдвигать, а перекидывать в другую очередь, возможно. Сами очереди реализуются традиционно - в виде кольцевых буферов.
В результате типичное время всех требуемых операций будет примерно O(1). Но периодически придётся перекидывать по нескольку элементов из одной очереди в другую. Ну и сами очереди при превышении буфера придётся переаллоцировать в более крупный буфер, ну это как обычно.
Логика будет сложноватая, но работать это должно эффективно.
Вариант 2
Можно, сделать связный список и ещё хранить ссылку на текущую его середину, от которой потом уже идти в следующий раз до актуальной середины, когда это понадобится. Для этого нужно будет ещё хранить текущее число элементов в очереди и порядковый номер элемента, на который указывает средний указатель (или это не надо? тут надо думать).
[ ] -> [ ] -> [ ] -> [ ] -> [ ]
 ^             ^             ^
 | начало      | середина    | конец

Эффективность этого метода будет зависеть от соотношения добавлений/удалений из очереди и вставок в середину. Если добавлений/удалений будет много, то идти до текущей середины придётся далеко. Впрочем, в варианте с двумя очередями в этом случае тоже придётся перекидывать много элементов из очереди в очередь, не уверен, что сложнее будет. Возможно, список будет эффективнее в этом случае.
А главное - сам алгоритм в случае списка будет гораздо проще, чем вариант с двумя очередями, особенно если вам придётся и сами очереди тоже "вручную" делать, а не брать готовые.
Впрочем, учитывая сложности пересчёта среднего элемента при добавлениях/удалениях, может этот алгоритм и не будет сильно проще.
P.S.

Какие есть источники, чтобы научится решать такие задачи?

Ну, есть всякие книги по типу "грокаем алгоритмы". И вообще, когда решаете много разнотипных задач на алгоритмы, то потом уже просто знаете, какой есть ассортимент коллекций и приёмов работы с ними, чтобы можно было подобрать подходящие инструменты под конкретную задачу. Нужно уметь оценивать алгоритмическую сложность тех или иных типовых действий и собирать оптимальную конфигурацию структур и методов под решение задачи.

@StanislavVolodarskiy Да, вы правы. Хотя число элементов всё-равно нужно хранить, чтобы понимать, на сколько сдвигать указатель на средний элемент.

Идея со списком выглядит привлекательней. Возможно проще будет запрограммировать 2 связных списка со счетчиками количества в каждом, в которых начало  второго списка это середина всей очереди. Тогда вставка в середину очереди -- это вставка в либо в начало второго списка, либо в конец первого.  При вставке  в конец очереди и выборке из начала может потребоваться перекидывание первого элемента второго списка в конец первого. Т.е. все операции это корректировка нескольких указателей и никакого поиска не требуется. Конечно, номер "x" (задаваемый в операциях P и M) надо хранить в элементе очереди

Как можно решить эту задачу эффективно? Какие приёмы можно использовать для решения?
Сперва надо решить как решать задачу. Можно симулировать очередь, можно изобрести какой-то способ без прямолинейной симуляции. Симуляция возможна за линейное время и линейную память. Понятно что линейное время не улучшить, но вдруг получится сделать меньшую память? Так что я потратил время на решение без симуляции, но ничего не придумалось. Делаем симуляцию.
deques
Первая идея - двусторонняя очередь. Но она не эффективна при вставке в середину. Опыт подсказывает использовать две очереди: одну от начала до середины, вторую от середины до конца. Надо будет следить за их длинами, но в целом ничего особенного.
Примеры я буду приводить на С++, у него богатая библиотека, которая хорошо подходит для этой задачи.
void deques() {
    std::deque<int> q1, q2;
    char c;
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        assert(q1.size() == q2.size() || q1.size() == q2.size() + 1); 
        int x;
        switch (c) {
        case 'P':
            std::cin >> x;
            q2.push_back(x);
            if (q2.size() > q1.size()) {
                q1.push_back(q2.front());
                q2.pop_front();
                assert(q1.size() == q2.size() + 1); 
            }
            break;
        case 'M':
            std::cin >> x;
            if (q1.size() > q2.size()) {
                q2.push_front(x);
                assert(q1.size() == q2.size()); 
            } else {
                q1.push_back(x);
                assert(q1.size() == q2.size() + 1); 
            }
            break;
        case 'C':
            std::cout << q1.front() << '\n';
            q1.pop_front();
            if (q1.size() < q2.size()) {
                q1.push_back(q2.front());
                q2.pop_front();
                assert(q1.size() == q2.size() + 1); 
            }
            break;
        }
        assert(q1.size() == q2.size() || q1.size() == q2.size() + 1); 
    }
}

vector
В комментариях упомянули вектор. Мол, современные компьютеры так устроены, что вектора очень эффективны и будут быстрее других, специализированных структур данных до размеров около миллиона элементов. Я вектор-скептик, но вариант с вектором очень прост, добавим его:
void vector() {
    std::vector<int> v;
    char c;
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        int x;
        switch (c) {
        case 'P':
            std::cin >> x;
            v.push_back(x);
            break;
        case 'M':
            std::cin >> x;
            v.insert(v.begin() + (v.size() + 1) / 2, x);
            break;
        case 'C':
            std::cout << v.front() << '\n';
            v.erase(v.begin());
            break;
        }
    }
}

forward_list
Единственная структура, которая позволяет вставку в середину за константу, список. В C++ есть двусвязный список list и односвязный forward_list. Для этой задачи достаточно односвязного.
Обычно односвязные списки пишут руками, но в данном я использовал готовый forward_list, что радикально уменьшает объём кода: не нужно самому выделять память, писать примитивные операции.
Это решение самое сложное: требуется хранить сам список, указатели на середину и конец, размер. И отладка далась с трудом, я упустил тонкий момент, когда указатели на середину и конец равны.
void forward_list() {
    std::forward_list<int> l;
    auto mid = l.end();
    auto last = l.end();
    size_t size = 0;
    char c;
    while (std::cin >> c) {
        int x;
        switch (c) {
        case 'P':
            std::cin >> x;
            if (last == l.end()) {
                l.push_front(x);
                mid = l.begin();
                last = l.begin();
            } else {
                l.insert_after(last, x);
                ++last;
                if (size % 2 == 0) {
                    ++mid;
                }
            }
            ++size;
            break;
        case 'M':
            std::cin >> x;
            if (last == l.end()) {
                l.push_front(x);
                mid = l.begin();
                last = l.begin();
            } else {
                l.insert_after(mid, x);
                if (mid == last) {
                    ++last;
                }
                if (size % 2 == 0) {
                    ++mid;
                }
            }
            ++size;
            break;
        case 'C':
            std::cout << l.front() << '\n';
            if (size == 1) {
                mid = l.end();
                last = l.end();
            } else {
                if (size % 2 == 0) {
                    ++mid;
                }
            }
            l.pop_front();
            --size;
            break;
        }
    }
}

Производительность
Раз есть три решения и утверждение что решение с вектором самое из них прекрасное, грех не проверить. Я написал main, которая конфигурирует cin/cout на скорость. Это типичный олимпиадный трюк, без него программы на C++, в которых перемежается ввод и вывод, очень тормозят. Вызывается программа так:

./a.out q < in.txt > out.txt


Единственный параметр выбирает вариант: q для очередей, v для вектора, l для списка. В in.txt входные данные, в out.txt результат.
int main(int, char *argv[]) {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    std::cin.tie(0);
    switch (argv[1][0]) {
    case 'q': deques      (); break;
    case 'v': vector      (); break;
    case 'l': forward_list(); break;
    }
}

Программа тестировалась на некоторых входах чтобы убедиться что все алгоритмы делают одно и то же. Потом я перешёл к замерам времени.
Я хотел измерить времена обработки очереди определённого размера. Сперва очередь заполнялась до этого размера командами P x. Затем один миллион раз повторялись четыре команды: M x, C, P x, C. Во второй фазе размер очереди почти не меняется, мы просто тестируем как быстро разные структуры справляются с очередью этого конкретного размера.
Размеры очереди были 10, 20, 30, ..., 100, 200, 300, ..., 1000, 2000, 3000, ..., 10000, 20000, 30000, ..., 100000.

И его нижняя часть покрупнее:

Выводы
Я сравню операции который делают список и вектор на левом конце графика (длина очереди 10 элементов), когда у вектора должно быть максимальное преимущество.



операция
что делает список
что делает вектор




M x
выделяет новый узелвставляет его в списокпереставляет указатель mid
перемещает 20 байт вправо на 4 байтазаписывает 4 байта


C
Удаляет узел в начале списка
перемещает 40 байт на 4 байта влево


P x
выделяет новый узелвставляет его в списокпереставляет указатель lastпереставляет указатель mid
записывает 4 байта в конец вектора


C
Удаляет узел в начале списка
перемещает 40 байт на 4 байта влево



Всего список делает два выделения и два освобождения памяти. Вектор вмещает вперёд-назад всего 100 байт в небольшом стационарном буфере, работы с памятью нет совсем, она вся делается в начале до первой итерации.
Односвязный список всегда быстрее вектора. Код с его участием сложный, но он делает мало операций.
Очереди показывают то же O-большое что и список, но константа хуже. Очередей две, требуется перекладка элементов между ними, сами очереди внутри устроены сложнее списков.
Вектор начинает хорошо и до тысячи элементов не уступает очереди, но потом сдаётся, O-большое не обманешь. Какой бы ни был великолепный кэш, скопировать тысячу элементов не получается так же быстро как переставить два указателя.
Напомню цитату, которая побудила меня провести анализ:

Кэш побеждает асимптотику. Берём динамический массив (в C++ это vector<T>, в C# это List<T>) и он, несмотря на копирования элементов, окажется быстрее чем списки. Если только речь не о миллионах элементов.

Если в этой цитате поправить "о миллионах элементов" на "о двух тысячах элементов" и "список" заменить на "очереди", она становится правдой. А пока обойти список у вектора не получилось.
Мертвы ли списки? Нет. Есть ряд задач в которых односвязный список обходит любые другие структуры данных и по константе и по O-большому.
Какие есть источники, чтобы научится решать такие задачи?
Ищите книги и учебные материлы по структурам данных. Когда вы освоитесь с массивами, списками, деревьями, очередями, стеками, и хеш-таблицами, порешайте олимпиадные задачи на структуры данных. Решить задач надо много, и будет у вас понимание какой контейнер каким концом прикладывать к задаче, чтобы она решилась быстро и в минимальной памяти.
P.S. Сказ про то как мужик из двух стеков очередь сделал
Я не стал добавлять ещё одно решение, и так ответ гигантский, но из двух стеков можно сделать двустроннюю очередь. Она будет во всём прекрасна, кроме ситуации когда вы попеременно вынимаете элементы с двух концов. В этой задаче такой ситуации не бывает: почитайте deques, там элементы удаляются только из начала очередей. Так вот, если deque заменить на такую двухстековую очередь, она может стать лучшей по производительности. Потому что не нужно выделять память под узлы списка, а операции со стеками (которые на самом деле вектора) могут быть быстрее, чем операции с deque.

Быстро вектора сдались. Но может это зависит от размера кэша процессора, например )

@CrazyElf, я добавил сравнение работы списка и вектора. Кэш не при чем. Он начинает играть роль, когда вектор в кэш помещается, а список, который расходует в 4-8 раз больше памяти, нет. Но в этой задаче когда мы доберёмся до границ кэша, вектор будет так отставать, что ему ничем не поможешь.
